# 'Statistics': amount of arrangements that end with 'A'

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I need to calculate the possible arrangements of the letters of the word 'statistics' which end with an A.

Without thinking about the double letters, the possible arrangements are:
$9! = 362880$. But I know that S occurs three times, T occurs three times and I occurs two times. So how can I calculate this?

Answer (score 1):

Place the A in the 10th position.  Choose three of the first nine positions for the Ss, three of the remaining six positions for the Ts, two of the remaining three positions for the Is, then place the C in the remaining position.

This can be done in $$\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{2} = \frac{9!}{3!6!} \cdot \frac{6!}{3!3!} \cdot \frac{3!}{2!1!} = \frac{9!}{3!3!2!1!}$$ ways.  One factor of $3!$ in the denominator represents the number of ways the three Ss could be permuted among themselves without producing an arrangement distinct from the given arrangement.  The other factor of $3!$ in the denominator represents the number of ways the three Ts could be permuted among themselves without producing an arrangement distinct from the given arrangement.   The factor of $2!$ in the denominator represents the number of ways the two Is could be permuted among themselves without producing an arrangement distinct from the given arrangement.

Comment: There is a [Math processing error] in the first number in your spoiler, so I can't read that number

Comment: I did not see an error on my end, but I tried removing the spoiler.  Let me know if you are still having trouble reading the answer.

Answer (score 0):

With $A$ fixed in the last position, and $9$ letters left to permute,
I'd prefer to directly use the formula $\dfrac{9!}{3!3!2!}$

with the denominator reflecting the repeated letters